USB-Serial I2C Bridge to PCF8574 (USB to IIC Adapter Module, USB to IIC I2C UART Converter) Cannot communicate
I'm writing an application to send I2C Commands to via USB-RS232 (Hardware B0CFK14PVS) to my PCF8574. I've struggle trying to send commands to the PCF8575 through B0CFK14PVS.
The few libraries I found to do this are basically for Raspberry Pi/Linux who use the smbus2 & smbus libraries but I haven't been able to find a Windows Library.
I have wrote the following code but I'm still cannot communicate with my relay board device via I²C. I know my hardware works because I use a Raspberry Pi 2 and works with no issues. But I need now to migrate this into Windows.
Please see below my code:
import serial
import time

port = "COM1"  # Change to the appropriate CH341SER COM Port
baud_rate = 115200
ser = serial.Serial(port, baud_rate)
pcf8574_address = 0x20 # Change this to the address of your PCF8574 if different

def i2c_start():
    ser.write(b'\x02')

def i2c_stop():
    ser.write(b'\x03')

def i2c_write_byte(byte):
    ser.write(byte.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))

def i2c_write(address, data):
    i2c_start()
    i2c_write_byte(address << 1)
    for byte in data:
        i2c_write_byte(byte)
    i2c_stop()

def write_coils(vector):
    """
    Function to write all coils in relay card. Receive an integer vector with output values
    """
    try:
        for i in range(0, 8):
            print ("i " + str (1))
            if vector[i] == 1:
                print ("vector" + str(vector))
                vector[i] = 0
            else:
                vector[i] = 1
        vector = vector[::-1]
        #coils.port = vector
        i2c_write(pcf8574_address, vector)
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error in write_coils:", e)

while True:
    write_coils([1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0])
    time.sleep(0.5)
    write_coils([0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1])
    time.sleep(0.5)


What is the sequence of bytes that you are hoping your code will generate at the COM port?

Your code seems to perform correctly, but is much more complex than it need be. The following is a simplified version, which generates the same output to the serial port as your original code:
import serial
import time

port = "COM1"  # Change to the appropriate CH341SER COM Port
baud_rate = 115200
ser = serial.Serial(port, baud_rate)
pcf8574_address = 0x20 # Change this to the address of your PCF8574 if different

def write_coils(data):
    addr = pcf8574_address << 1
    ser.write([0x02])   # Start byte
    ser.write([addr])
    ser.write(data)
    ser.write([0x03])   # Stop byte

while True:
    write_coils([1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0])
    time.sleep(0.5)
    write_coils([0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1])
    time.sleep(0.5)

The result of the first call to write_coils(), i.e. write_coils([1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0]) is to send the folowing to the serial port:
02 40 01 00 01 00 01 00 01 00 03

I have verified that this is the case both for your original code, and for my shorter version, by reading from the port with an Arduino device. If this is not what you had intended to send to your device, then it should be a very simple matter to edit my code accordingly.
